# ERROR: Fetching the page failed because other errors. Twitter Cards Issue

Tags: ssl, twitter, sslhandshakeexception

When I go to https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator and enter https://piktoria.com/blog/instagram-to-drive-sales/ and adlatch.com

Validator says - **Unable to render Card preview**

**ERROR: Fetching the page failed because other errors.**

So because of that when i share anything on twitter, don't get any snippets, tried twitter support they say:

"There's something wrong with your SSL setup - I am seeing SslHandshakeException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name at remote address in my debug log which I suspect means that your server name does not match the certificate, or something similar."

Can anyone help in solving this issue

Comment: I got the same answer from the validator. I am using letsencrypt.org for the SSL certificate. Could it be that you are also using them and that letsencrypt is not recognized as valid by Twitter?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened with me also But i managed to Fix It when twiiter told me to check SSL Settings

I got the point The problem was From AES256 and AES128 (For NgiNx Web Server) You need to enable AES128

Here is Snippet

```
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384!AES128:!3DES';
```

As you see in the Snippet the AES128 is Disabled(!)

you need to remove the ! From AES128 So the Code will be:

```
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!3DES';
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a post a bit old, but you can get this error due to a different TLS configuration.

When I looked into my webserver error logs, I encountered the following error:

```
2021/05/12 19:41:31 [crit] 16585#16585: *44673 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14209102:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: X.X.X.X, server: X.X.X.X:443
```

It looks like **twitter**, as of now, **does not support `TLSv1.3`** for getting the cards, and the solution is to also enable `TLSv1.2`. If you use the intermediate configuration from Mozilla's ssl-config tool that is good enough.

See https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=nginx&version=1.17.7&config=intermediate&openssl=1.1.1d&guideline=5.6